# Multiprocessing not improving performance, and no output printed

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have written a function that takes vibration data in a proprietary format and looks for 60 Hz noise. It loops through reading a portion of the file (known as a block), applying an FFT to that block, and then checking the magnitude of the bin closest to 60 Hz. This process takes about 20 minutes due to the file size. The portion of the function which takes the longest is reading a block into memory into a Pandas `DataFrame`. I was hoping that using multiprocessing would speed it up, but I'm not having any luck. Here is my function which currently works as intended:

```
from scipy.fftpack import fft
from custom import load_dataset
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Process

def assessment():
    # Code to read a database to get the path to the file, file length, sample rate, and the accelerometer name
    # Code to determine block size based on sample rate
    magnitudes = []
    for block in range(0, file_length, block_size):
        df = load_dataset(file_path, channels=accel_name, start_block=block, nblocks=block_size)
        # Apply FFT
        N = len(df)
        nyquist = sample_rate/2
        X = np.linspace(0.0, nyquist, int(N/2))
        Y = fft(df)
        y = 2/N*np.abs(Y[0:np.int(N/2)])
        res = min(enumerate(X), key=lambda x: abs(60-x[1])) # Find bin closest to 60 Hz
        magnitude = y[res[0]] # Get magnitude of desired bin
        magnitudes.append(magnitude) # Store in list
    return magnitudes
```

I tried adding this to the bottom, but the code ran for 20 minutes and then output nothing:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=assessment)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

EDIT: I'm hoping this revision is something that can take advantage of threading or multiprocessing more easily:

```
def assessment(file_path, accel_name, block, block_size):
    df = load_dataset(file_path, channels=accel_name, start_block=block, nblocks=block_size)
    # Apply FFT
    N = len(df)
    nyquist = sample_rate/2
    X = np.linspace(0.0, nyquist, int(N/2))
    Y = fft(df)
    y = 2/N*np.abs(Y[0:np.int(N/2)])
    res = min(enumerate(X), key=lambda x: abs(60-x[1])) # Find bin closest to 60 Hz
    magnitude = y[res[0]] # Get magnitude of desired bin
    return magnitude

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Code to set all the variables that need to be passed to assessment function
    temp = []
    for block in range(0, file_length, block_size):
        temp.append((file_path, accel_name, block, block_size)) #create list of tuples
    p = Process(target=assessment, args=temp)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Comment: A question title should describe a **specific technical problem**. Whether the person encountering that problem is a beginner is completely immaterial: the long-term purpose of a question title is to help other people with the same problem find your question and learn from its answers, instead of needing to ask their own question. (I've edited it towards that end).

Comment: That said, what part of your code is _expected_ to output anything? I don't see any `print()`s anywhere. Just `return`ing a value to the top level only outputs it _at the REPL_, not in a standalone program.

Comment: The other thing here is that you're getting no benefit from `multiprocessing` at all when you only start one process with it -- you get the exact same performance you would have had if you'd just started that one process at the top level, maybe a little slower because of serialization overhead. You should be starting one process _per block_ if you want any parallelism.

Comment: Another thing -- if the work is in pandas, you may not need to use multiprocessing in the first place; pandas tries to release the GIL when it can (and also tries to do threading internally when it can). That means that the IO, if it's not hardware-bound in the first place, may be able to get the same gains from threading (if there are any gains to be had at all) without needing to eat serialization overhead; and for CPU, if pandas is already successfully multithreading, adding more processes is just going to increase contention and make performance worse instead of better.

Comment: So the first thing to do is to look at your system's performance metrics and figure out if it's bottlenecked already and where. If it's bottlenecked on IO, trying to get more reads through that bottleneck will just make things worse. If it's bottlenecked on CPU across all cores, trying to do more work at the same time will just make it worse. It's only if you have unused IO throughput or unused CPU cycles that there are gains to be had by parallelizing in the first place, so measure those things before you start.

Comment: This function is one of many functions looking at different data sets all related to the same test. Eventually, this function will take test number as an input, search a database for the corresponding data file, do the steps shown above, check the magnitude against a given threshold, write "Good" or "Not Good" to a dictionary e.g. `status[accel_name] = "Good"`, and then repeat for all the other accelerometers in the file. The resulting dictionary would be used by another function to save those statuses to the database.

Comment: Prior to adding the multiprocessing code, the `assessment` function caused the following metrics on Task Manager: CPU increased from 10% to 40%, Memory stayed at 32%, and Disk increased from 0% to 6%. I can't see the individual cores using Task Manager and I don't have admin rights to use Resource Monitor.

Comment: Okay, so there is headroom available to use -- so you can probably gain from parallelism, though it may still be better to use threading than multiprocessing depending on the details (specifically whether you're CPU-bound in code that holds the GIL or not; and how expensive it is to serialize/deserialize the results). That "how expensive it is" can be estimated based on how large `y[res[0]]` is; if it's tiny, then what you're paying for multiprocessing over multithreading is fairly small... but again, you'll need to split into multiple `Process`es regardless if you want any gains at all.

Comment: (Remember, the whole idea behind multiprocessing is to have multiple processes running at the same time that don't need to fight over Python's global interpreter lock; when you make only one `Process` and have the main thread waiting for it, you still only have one process doing any work at a time, so how is it expected to be any faster than the code was without using `multiprocessing` at all?)

Comment: I'm having a hard time wrapping my mind around this. To me, each time the `for loop` repeats is a process. Is it not possible to have some of those repeats running in parallel rather than sequentially?

Comment: Each `multiprocessing.Process` instance represents a process. To have each `for` loop be a process, you need to create a new `Process` in each iteration of the `for` loop, and have _that `Process`_ do the actual work. Right now, you're doing your whole loop in just one `Process`, so there's no benefit over doing the whole loop in the main thread; it's still just one process / one thread doing all the work.

Comment: That is to say: multiprocessing doesn't magically parallelize your loops; it's your job, as the developer, to decide where the boundary points are. (That's important, because crossing those boundaries is expensive -- you can make performance much worse than it would be otherwise if you create a process boundary where there isn't enough work done to justify the cost of crossing a serialization/deserialization barrier to get the results back).

Comment: (depending on how multiprocessing is configured, getting data _into_ the separate process can also be expensive -- it depends on whether you have it set to fork a subprocess per `Process` instance, in which case they get a copy of the data they had at creation time "for free"; or set to have a long-running pool of processes, in which case data needs to be fed into a pool member after it was already running).

Comment: Because each `Process` created starts only one process, `args` needs to contain _only the arguments for that one process_.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to assert that this will actually succeed in making your process faster -- see comments on the question for a discussion of caveats involved -- but if you wanted to parallelize it with multiprocessing, that might look like the following:

```
def main():
    # Code to set all the variables that need to be passed to assessment function
    processes = [
        Process(target=assessment, args=(file_path, accel_name, block, block_size))
        for block in range(0, file_length, block_size)
    ]
    for p in processes:
        p.start()
    for p in processes:
        p.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Note that we create one `Process` object per concurrent operation anticipated.

Note that just `return`ing the value doesn't convey it to the parent process -- you should use a `multiprocessing.Queue` or `multiprocessing.Pipe` for that; or just write it to storage direct from the child process and avoid the transfer cost altogether.